# Best Approach for Flat table representing data from multiple sources

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using SQL Server 2014.
We have a couple dozen tables that we create reports against.  What is the best approach report against all these tables with respect to SQL.  Our need is a single flat table with select/specific columns from a number of these tables.

Options

1. Create views across the existing live tables using relationships
   to produce the single representation of our data
2. Create some process that is scheduled and run at different times of the data to extract columnar data and insert/update an existing table (then
   perform reporting against that table)
3. Rely on c#/data access code to collect data and push to the reporting tool d) others?

Is there a optimized way to use data warehouse features within SQL to create this single aggregated table?

thx

Comment: What is the issue you're trying to resolve? Performance?

Comment: Start with 1.  Move to 2. as needed.  You may discover that a single flat table is not really what you want, and move to a dimensional model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling.  If you store the data in a table, you'll probably want to use a Clustered Columnstore table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql

Comment: I had heard there were some features in SQL 2014+ that would help create some flat-data warehouse table based on existing tables for the purposes of reporting.  I was thinking that it might be more efficient than using views.  Maybe this is the Columnstore table you mention.

Comment: Yep.  Clustered Columnstore.  You would still write the view (that's why you start with 1.).  Then later switch to loading a table through the view.